# How can I add a plural-s after a Sphinx :class: directive

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have this problem all the time that I want to write a docstring like this:

```
def foo(arg):
   '''Add ``arg`` to the list of :class:`foo.bar.baz.Argument`s.'''
   pass
```

However, that doesn't work, Sphinx will warn that

```
py:class reference target not found: foo.bar.baz.Argument`s
```

so it's treating the `s` after the closing backtick as part of the class name. This does not happen with e.g. punctuation marks like the dot `.`.
Is there anything to be done about this, except adding a space between the class name and the Plural-s (which looks crazy)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to use [backslash-escaped whitespace](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism).

```
def foo(arg):
   '''Add ``arg`` to the list of :class:`foo.bar.baz.Argument`\ s.'''
   pass
```

Comment: I had been using the above, but newer python versions are giving a deprecation warning that `\ ` is an invalid escape sequence. Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: @youngmit: Cannot reproduce. It works for me with Python 3.9.1 and Sphinx 3.4.3. However, there have been changes to the treatment of escape sequences (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335971/407651). Does it work with two backslashes or a raw string?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by just using a single backslash, but add an `r` prefix. This way, sphinx still gets the `\ ` escape sequence and interprets it properly, but python ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer of @mzjn, but in recent versions of Python you have to include two backslashes, e.g.:

```py
def foo(arg):
   """Add ``arg`` to the list of :class:`foo.bar.baz.Argument`\\ s."""
```

As pointed out before, a *raw string* ("r-string") also does the job with one backslash:

```py
def foo(arg):
   r"""Add ``arg`` to the list of :class:`foo.bar.baz.Argument`\ s."""
```