# Getting PEP8 "invalid escape sequence" warning trying to escape parentheses in a regex

Tags: python, regex, pep8, python-re

I am trying to escape a string such as this:

```py
string = re.split(")(", other_string)
```

Because not escaping those parentheses gives me an error. But if I do this:

```py
string = re.split("\)\(", other_string)
```

I get a warning from PEP8 that it's an invalid escape sequence. Is there a way to do this properly?

Putting 'r' in front of the string does not fix it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably are looking for [this](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) which would mean your string would be written as `string = r")("` which would be escaped. Though that is from 2008 and in python 2 which is being phased out. What the `r` does is make it a "raw string"

See: [How to fix "<string> DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335970/how-to-fix-string-deprecationwarning-invalid-escape-sequence-in-python) as well.

What you're dealing with is string literals which can be seen in the [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

UPDATE For Edit in Question:

If you're trying to split on ")(" then here's a working example that doesn't throw PEP8 warnings:

```
import re

string = r"Hello my darling)(!"
print(string)
string = re.split(r'\)\(', string)
print(string)
```

Which outputs:

```
Hello )(world!
['Hello ', 'world!']
```

Or you can escape the backslash explicitly by using two backslashes:

```
import re

string = r"Hello )(world!"
print(string)
string = re.split('\\)\\(', string)
print(string)
```

Which outputs the same thing:

```
Hello )(world!
['Hello ', 'world!']
```

Comment: The raw string formatting r"str" doesn't seem to work to fix the issue in Python 3.8 but the double backslash works great, thanks!