Python Triple Quoted comments choke on too many backslashes
Python displays SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\ ' when I am drawing a tree structure in a triple quoted comment string:
     A
    / \
   B   C
  / \   \
 D   E   F


If you want those backslashes to be treated literally, rather than the start of an escape sequence, then you need a raw string literal - put an r in front of it.  Triple vs. single quoted has nothing to do with this.

dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52335970/674039

You can define it as raw string with triple quotes.
r'''
     A
    / \
   B   C
  / \   \
 D   E   F
'''


You should escape \ with \ i.e. \\.
Can you try below:
tree = """
     A
    / \\
   B   C
  / \\   \\
 D   E   F
 """
 
print(tree)

I have confirmed the results on 2 different environments,
It outputs correctly:

